# Setting up RoadKill

Tags: wiki, roadkill-wiki

I am trying to setup a internal wiki site for project documentation project.  I am using roadkill because I have a IIS server and a .net environment.

So the installation instructions aren't much.  Unzip the files onto a site directory.  Navigate to `http://arwiki`

Should be that simple, however, I get an error about directory browsing and it looks like there is no MVC mapping in Global.asax.  It points to a internal dll so it is hard to determine what I did wrong?

Has anyone setup Roadkill and know what I did incorrectly?

Also there is no tag for roadkill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask for help on the issues board -

https://bitbucket.org/yetanotherchris/roadkill/issues?status=new&status=open

However I can tell you that the problem is most likely that you don't have MVC installed on IIS (if it's Windows Server 2008). You might also need to enable ISAPI filters, they can be turned off.

The ASP.NET web installer contains the MVC bits you need, although Roadkill does come bundled with these.

Comment: it was that my app pool somehow was v2.0xxx instead of v4.0xxx.  That started the wizard.  Now I have another issue but I will use the forum you suggested.